# Using cursors in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

Here is my stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpdateDataInBapMidTable (
   @companyName varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @companyName = 'nürnberger'

    DECLARE @tableNameMid varchar(50) , @tableNameIn varchar(50) , @queryToCreateTable nvarchar (500) , @queryToAddColumn nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @queryToUpdateBapMid nvarchar(500)
    SET @tableNameMid = 'BAP_'+@companyName+'_MID'
    SET @tableNameIn = 'BAP_'+@companyName+'_IN'
    DECLARE @COGI varchar (50)
    SET @COGI = ''

SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @collectionOfGesellschaft_id nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE myCursor cursor FOR
    SELECT distinct gesellschaft_id from CRM_Wifo_GmbH.dbo.vertrag_168 where gesellschaft like '%nürnberger%'

    open myCursor
    DECLARE @collectionOfGesellschaft_id1 nvarchar(100)

    set @collectionOfGesellschaft_id  = '('
    fetch next from myCursor into @collectionOfGesellschaft_id1
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
    set @collectionOfGesellschaft_id = @collectionOfGesellschaft_id + @collectionOfGesellschaft_id1 + ' ,'

    fetch next from myCursor into @collectionOfGesellschaft_id1
    END
    set @collectionOfGesellschaft_id = SUBSTRING(@collectionOfGesellschaft_id,1,LEN(@collectionOfGesellschaft_id)-1) + ')'
    SET @COGI = @collectionOfGesellschaft_id
    CLOSE myCursor
    DEALLOCATE myCursor                         
    go

SET @queryToUpdateBapMid = N'select distinct b.*,v.vertrag_id,v.VersicherungsscheinNummer 
from CRM_Wifo_GmbH.dbo.vertrag_168 v,temp_universa b where v.VersicherungsscheinNummer like ''%'' + b.VSNR + ''%''  and v.gesellschaft_id in' + @COGI
EXEC(@queryToUpdateBapMid)

END
```

`@companyName` is set for my testing purpose. when I execute the cursor only, it runs fine. but in the stored procedure it shows followingerror :

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspUpdateDataInBapMidTable, Line 33
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'myCursor'.*
>
> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@COGI".*
>
> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@queryToUpdateBapMid".*

I have declare these two variable in the starting of the SP, but they are showing this error. and what is the problem with the line

```
 DEALLCOATE myCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the word `go` just after the line `DEALLOCATE myCursor`.

`GO` isn't part of either SQL in general or specifically Transact-SQL. It is a keyword recognised by tools like SQL Server Management Studio or `sqlcmd` as a batch delimiter. When `GO` is encountered, your script is split at that point and the part preceding `GO` gets executed separately from the part following it.

The `go` in your particular script splits it prematurely. It essentially leaves the initial `BEGIN` unclosed, and that actually is what the error is about, although, granted, the message may seem somewhat confusing.

Anyway, that was your issue, so, just remove the `go`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i sorted it myself 15 hours ago.

Comment: Yes, I was somewhat late to the show, sorry. :) Glad you were able figure this out yourself.